# Apache mod_rewrite redirect, keep sub-directory name

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I'm wondering if this is possible.

I have a single page site in which I'd like to incorporate a trailing slash with a file name that anchors to a section on that site.  I'm trying to avoid using hash or hash-bangs.

For example; `www.example.com/recent`

Right now, I'm removing any trailing slash, but I get a 404 with `/recent` because it's expecting a file.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Is it possible to redirect to `www.example.com`, but still maintain the `/recent` without the server thinking it's a file so I can read it client-side (php/js)? More so that I can keep using the back and forward buttons.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TBH it is not 100% clear for me what you want. As I understand you want URL `www.example.com/recent` to be rewritten (internal redirect, when URL remains unchanged in browser) to `www.example.com/index.php?page=recent` (or something like that).

```
DirectorySlash Off
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# remove trailing slash if present
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]

# do not do anything for already existing files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule .+ - [L]

# rewrite all non-existing resources to index.php
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

With the above rules (that need to be placed in .htaccess in website root folder) this can be achieved. Request for `www.example.com/recent` will be rewritten to  `www.example.com/index.php?page=recent` so your single-page server side script knows which URL was requested. The same will be with any other non-existing resource e.g. `www.example.com/hello/pink/kitten` => `www.example.com/index.php?page=hello/pink/kitten`.

It may not be necessary to pass originally requested URI as a `page` parameter as you should be able to access it in PHP via `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` anyway.

---

If I misunderstood you and this is not what you want then you have to clarify your question (update it with more details, make it sound clear).

Comment: Sorry for my poorly worded question and I do appreciate you taking the time to answer.  What you have there is what I was looking for!  My question now is; in the last rule there is no R=301 - should I be concerned about that if the person enters in no trailing slash?  Specifically for SEO or my log file filling up?

Comment: If person enters URL with trailing slash (e.g. `www.example.com/recent/`) it will be redirected (301 Permanent Redirect) to `www.example.com/recent` (this will be the new URL visible in browser), which then will be silently rewritten to `/index.php?page=recent`. The correct link should be WITHOUT trailing slash. And if person enters it WITH, then it will be removed with proper SEO-friendly redirect code. You do not need `R=301` flag in last rule as it defeats the point of having nice URL (`www.example.com/recent`).